# SQL Count the distinct values that accomplish two condition for a single row

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Hello I'm using google BigQuerry and I'm trying to get from a table a the total number of distinct values that accomplish two values for a row. Let's explain it:

I have a table like:

```
userId  |  platform
123     |  iOS
123     |  android
123     |  other
124     |  android
124     |  iOS
125     |  android
125     |  other
126     |  other
```

I want to get the total number of users (Distinct userId) who have the platform iOS and Android, both platforms not per separate.
The result should be 2 in this case.

I tried with:

```
SELECT count(distinct A.grupo1) 
FROM mytable B
JOIN EACH
    (SELECT userId as grupo1 
     FROM mytable 
     WHERE platform = 'ios'  
     GROUP BY grupo1) A 
ON A.grupo1=B.userId
```

Doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know BigQuerry, but since you tagged the question with sql I assume sql will work.

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct userid)
FROM (
    SELECT userid 
    FROM mytable 
    WHERE platform in ('iOS', 'android')
    GROUP BY userid
    HAVING COUNT(distinct platform) = 2
)
```

Comment: I think the distinct is redundant here, otherwise seems like the correct way to do it

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT corpus, COUNT(*) c 
FROM (
 SELECT word, corpus
 FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare] 
 WHERE word='brave' OR word='profession'
 GROUP EACH BY word, corpus
)
GROUP BY corpus
HAVING c=2
```

There are 12 Shakespeare books that have both the word 'brave' and 'profession'.